# What algorithm ethereum uses to generate wallets?

Tags: wallets, private-key, public-key

The wallet string is the public key, while the private key is used to unlock the account and should be kept in secret. What algorithm is used to generate this pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out after some research about elliptic curve and its implementation in ethereum/bitcoin - secp256k1
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1

Comment: As far as I can tell, Vitalik Buterin has also suggested that ECDSA with `ed25519` can be used, and possibly that a future migration to `Lamport signatures` when Quantum Computers become viable. Source: http://bit.ly/2fWJYJ3